# removing span tag within body tag

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have the following html:

```html
<p>
I wanna remove this <span class="highlight1">highlight</span> when user selects text 
and presses a button. This shouln't remove the following <span class="highlight1">highlight</span>.
</p>
```

When user selects **text** and does some action (e.g. pressing a button), I want that specific text to be unhighlighted. I can't figure out how to do this with vanilla JS :(
I only have the following JS code to capture when the text selection is on a highlighted text:

```
//Assume code is within an event handler...
var text_selection = window.getSelection();

if (text_selection.anchorNode.parentNode.className === 'highlight1')
{
  //unhighlight
  console.log("unhighlight");
}
```

Comment: If the "highlighted" text is always only text you can replace the span with (`.replaceWith()`) a text node (`.createTextNode()`) from the text content of the span.

Comment: Please add a full code example. 1. `text_selection` is not defined. 2. Where is your click event (Some action)?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: your code is not valid........

Comment: Its more like pseudocode, thought that would be fine...

Comment: @EzraSiton A [mcve] would be good, but it isn't really needed. From the text we know that OP want's to get rid of the "highlighting" (`<span class="highlight1">...</span>`). We also know that OP is able to get that `<span>` element (_"when the text selection is on a highlighted text"_). It's missing the information if the "highlight" feature is restricted to text or if it can also contain other markup.

Comment: @Andreas its only restricted to text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `<span class="highlight1">...</span>` will always only contain text and no other markup then you can "remove" the highlighting by replacing (-> [`.replaceWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith)) the `<span>` element with a text node created from the content of the `<span>`

`span` in the example would be the `text_selection.anchorNode.parentNode` from your pseudo code.

```js
const textNode = document.createTextNode(span.textContent);
span.replaceWith(textNode);
```

Example:

```js
/* setTimeout so you can "see" the removal */
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelectorAll(".highlight1").forEach(span => {
    const textNode = document.createTextNode(span.textContent);
    span.replaceWith(textNode);
  })
}, 2000);
```

```css
.highlight1 { color: red }
```

```html
<p>
I wanna remove this <span class="highlight1">highlight</span> when user selects text 
and presses a button. This shouln't remove the following <span class="highlight1">highlight</span>.
</p>
```